# Searching within LyX documents

Tags: lyx

I have a bunch of LyX docs in a folder.

I want to search within the document for few terms so that I can select the documents of my interest. E.g. I have the CV's of 20 persons in LyX format. I have to search which of these CV's mention xml.

The Windows utility does not allow search within the LyX file. What are my options? I do not want to generate pdf and do so.

Also is there any LaTeX package, which generates tags from document content?

Comment: Your second question is so completely different that I think you should write a new question about that.

Comment: Use `grep`. A .lyx file is just a text file. I don't know what the best way to do that on Windows is.

Comment: Or if you want a Windows-hackishy solution (it pains me to suggest this), rename your .lyx files to .txt and then use the Windows search within file option.

Comment: IMHO this question does not fall in the scope of TSX. It is more a Windows and file searching option than a TeX question.

Answer (score 2):

## Many files

Had you used Linux I would have said `grep xml *.lyx`, but as you are on Windows that is not available. There are several programs that offer similar functionality though including [AstroGrep](http://astrogrep.sourceforge.net) (via https://superuser.com/a/60174) and [Grepwin](https://code.google.com/p/grepwin/) (via [Paolo Cereda in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/13033384#13033384)). A more drastic solution is [Cygwin](http://www.cygwin.com), which is a Linux-like environment for Windows. In the Cygwin terminal you can use `grep` as mentioned above.

There is a similar tool available in the Windows command line though, `findstr` (via https://superuser.com/a/198474). Open a command prompt, `cd` to the directory containing the `.lyx` files, and execute

```
findstr /s /m xml *.lyx
```

You can save the output to a text file with `> out.txt`, i.e.

```
findstr /s /m xml *.lyx > out.txt
```

## For a small number of files

You could open all of the files at the same time in LyX and use LyX's advanced search function:

Edit --> Find & replace (Advanced). Go to the Settings tab in the search panel and select *Open files*.

[image]

Comment: There are more than 500 files. Is opening all the files feasible?

Comment: @user34083 Probably not, I updated my answer a little.

Answer (score 0):

Under Windows, one can use [FART](http://fart-it.sourceforge.net/) - **F**ind **A**nd **R**eplace **T**ext. FART provides a minimalistic interface to the well-known [`grep`](http://www.gnu.org/software/grep/manual/). The command line option would look like

```
fart --count --ignore-case *.lyx XML
```

This would only display the filenames (`--count`) and perform a case-insensitive search (`--ignore-case`) of the phrase `XML` inside `*.lyx`. As output you'll see a count of the number of occurrences of `XML` in each file, with only matched files being displayed.